# Custom font in Xcode does not work

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts

Added custom font as tutorial suggest [here](https://medium.com/yay-its-erica/how-to-import-fonts-into-xcode-swift-3-f0de7e921ef8).

- font is in “Build Phases” -> “Bundle Resources”
- font names is in your plist

[image]

[image]

[image]

But still neither from Stroyboard nor from code I can set font of an `UILabel`. What am I missing?

Comment: Try to use the font without a space in its name.

Answer (score 1):

Please read carefully this [article](https://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/#findfontname).

> Step 5: Find the name of the font
>
> This is a common pitfall for many people trying to include custom
>   fonts into their iOS app. This was something that eluded me before as
>   well and it’s the fact that when you specify which font you want to
>   use, you’re not specifying the file name but rather, the font name.
>   The tricky part is that the font name may not be what you expect. It
>   could be very different than any of the visible font names that you
>   can see.
>
> So in order to easily find the name of the font that you want to use,
>   you can output something to the console window and see for yourself.

You can print names for all fonts available for developer with this code:

`for family in UIFont.familyNames {
     print("\(family)")
     for names in UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: family){
         print("== \(names)")
     }
}`

It will produce output like this:

[image: console output]

Find yours and use it with:

`label.font = UIFont(name: "SFProText-Heavy", size: 14.0)`

To add custom font to interface builder open `Font Book` from `Spotlight Search` and drag and drop your font there

[image]

[image]